# After converting multiple dataframes into respective nc files how to save those nc files with the original names and a word in windows using python

Tags: python, netcat

I have some `nc` files.Their names are `File1.nc`, `File2.nc`, `File3.nc`, etc. I have extracted data for every `nc` file, and I have made `dataframe` for each `nc` file after doing some calculation. Now after making the dataframes, I want to save them as new `nc` file with a path and a word adding at the last of the original name. What I want to say is like if the path is "c:/my document/convert", then the new `nc` file name will be c:/my document/convert/File1_calculated.nc.

what I have done so far for a single file is:

```
original_name="c:/my document/File1.nc"

prefix = original_name.rsplit('.')[0]
fileoutput = prefix + '_calculated.nc

path_name='c:/my document/convert'

output_name=os.path.join(path_name,fileoutput)

xr.Dataset(df.to_xarray()).to_netcdf(output_name)
```

This code runs. But when I check the convert folder. It shows empty.
Please help me.

In my code 'df' is the `dataframe` which I made after calculation for the file `File1.nc`. I use windows operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code you are not getting just `File1` as a prefix:

```
original_name="c:/my document/File1.nc"
 
prefix = original_name.rsplit('.')[0]

print(prefix)
'c:/my document/File1'
```

you may do instead:

```
fn_prefix = original_name.split("/")[-1][:-3]
fileoutput = fn_prefix + '_calculated.nc
```